# JMeter- load testing on live and dynamic graph

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I am doing load testing of my application through JMeter. It consist of some live graphs of temperature vs time. Is it possible to perform load test on it ?

Comment: You can do load testing on API's which are called behind to load Graphs. In addition, you can check rendering time.

Comment: Thankyou..Can u share any specific link or url regarding this so that i can get more clearity on load testing on graph. Any example or something u have please share here.

Comment: Which library/framework are you using for Graphs? This post might help you but it is not specific to Graphs http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-test-plan.html

Comment: I am using jmeter for testing graph. The graph is dynamic is so value is changing every time

Comment: It doesn't matter. All you have to test is back-end API's which loads the dynamic values.